# Flash Security Sandbox: crossDomain.xml not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, upload, crossdomain.xml

I have written a simple upload component in Flash, but I am now having issues in uploading due to a Security Sandbox error. I now know this is due to the fact I am uploading from one domain, to another, but 1, this used to work, 2, i have implemented a cross domain xml file by placing it in the root of the domain I'm serving from. There is also the following code at the top of my movie that used to work:

```
System.security.allowDomain("*");
```

Here is the plan, upload from admin.subdomain.serveraddress.net to serving.serveraddress.net, but it doesn't work!

Below is the cross domain file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
    <allow-access-from domain="*.serveraddress.net" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Should the above XML work? Help! :)

Comment: Are you using a different port to 80?

Comment: Nope. Everything is normal :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a crossdomain.xml (mind the case here, all lowercase) on the machine you are attempting to connect to. In this case you are connecting to serving.serveraddress.net from admin.subdomain.serveraddress.net.

Place the crossdomain.xml file you have pasted above in the root of serving.serveraddress.net so that it would be accessible from http://serving.serveraddress.net/crossdomain.xml and it should be fine.

If this still doesn't work, please provide more details.